# On scala project - Getting error GC overhead limit exceeded when running sbt test command

Tags: scala, configuration, garbage-collection, sbt

I'm new in scala programming and getting `GC overhead limit exceeded` error when I execute `sbt test` command in one of big scala project. Anyone knows how can I solve this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I got help from my friends :)

Increase the memory option by executing with -mem option for example:

`sbt -mem 2048 test`

**Other options:**

For Mac & Linux user:

if we need to execute this a lot. We can update the `.bash_profile` file and add below command:

`export SBT_OPTS="-Xmx2G"`

**Other solution (works with Windows as well):**

There's also a specific `sbtopts` file where you can persist this memory setting:

Find a file in Mac/Linux:
`/usr/local/etc/sbtopts`
Or in Windows
`C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\conf`

and add below configuration:

```
# set memory options
#
-mem   2048
```

Hopefully any of these tips will help someone with this problem.

EDIT:

If anyone using IntelliJ IDEA like me, you can increase the sbt memory usage using the VM Parameters as in the picture below.

```
-Xmx4G
```

[image]

Comment: Changed as 2048 but still fail

Answer (score 3):

Having a look at the [launcher script for running sbt](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/b28d203910e68f9051f33b4821f956c234583eb9/src/universal/bin/sbt), which on my system resides at `/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt`, we see the following:

```
declare -r sbt_opts_file=".sbtopts"
declare -r etc_sbt_opts_file="/etc/sbt/sbtopts"
declare -r dist_sbt_opts_file="${sbt_home}/conf/sbtopts"

...

# Here we pull in the default settings configuration.
[[ -f "$dist_sbt_opts_file" ]] && set -- $(loadConfigFile "$dist_sbt_opts_file") "$@"

# Here we pull in the global settings configuration.
[[ -f "$etc_sbt_opts_file" ]] && set -- $(loadConfigFile "$etc_sbt_opts_file") "$@"

#  Pull in the project-level config file, if it exists.
[[ -f "$sbt_opts_file" ]] && set -- $(loadConfigFile "$sbt_opts_file") "$@"

#  Pull in the project-level java config, if it exists.
[[ -f ".jvmopts" ]] && export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS $(loadConfigFile .jvmopts)"

run "$@"
```

Thus we can put configuration settings in:

```
.jvmopts
.sbtopts
/etc/sbt/sbtopts
${sbt_home}/conf/sbtopts
```

For example, [`typelevel/cats`](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/2718d5ebc76ab1446654d71d29199badaa3fd7be/.jvmopts) project uses `.jvmopts` to set `-Xmx3G`. Alternatively we could do

```
echo "-mem 2048" >> .sbtopts
```

Regarding environmental variables`sbt -h` documents that

```
  JAVA_OPTS          environment variable, if unset uses "$java_opts"
  .jvmopts           if this file exists in the current directory, its contents
                     are appended to JAVA_OPTS
  SBT_OPTS           environment variable, if unset uses "$default_sbt_opts"
  .sbtopts           if this file exists in the current directory, its contents
                     are prepended to the runner args
```

For example,

```
export JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2G
sbt
```

should run sbt with 2G of memory.

Note that if you are running tests in [forked JVM](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html), then you can increase memory via `javaOptions` setting in `build.sbt` like so:

```
Test / fork := true
Test / javaOptions ++= Seq("-Xmx4G")
```

[VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/) is a useful tool to see what settings were passed to a JVM process when experimenting with different ways of configuring SBT.