# How to set memory on a per project basis in sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, config

Currently, for a scala project I have to increase the memory to run its test via:

```
sbt -mem 2000 test
```

to set it to 2 GB.

I want to store the memory config in a file file inside the project (shared via git) so that every developer has this setting in place. Is that possible and if so how do I achieve that?

When I run:

```
sbt -v
[process_args] java_version = '8'
# Executing command line:
java
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-jar
/usr/share/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar
```

I see that it defaults to 1024 MB, yet I fail to see where it gets that default values from nor how how to override it.

Sbt's man pages references as default: `$sbt_mem, which is $(get_mem_opts $sbt_mem` yet this also does not help my understanding on where to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating `.jvmopts` file at the root of the project like so

```
-Xmx2G
```

Also consider related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54725010/5205022